# mysql unique (multiple keys )

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

hi guys I have attached a pic for the table structure..
[image: mysql unique]

**The problem**

I am adding a new record to db and it says its duplicated when `title` is different is there something wrong on the way I have structured all three to be unique?

I need the title,parent, eid to be unique as only if all three have the same data in it, if one of the fields is different treat it as a non duplicate

**UPDATED**
The title `bla bla` does not exist on db yet

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`,`title`,`parent`,`lang`)VALUES(1,'Bla bla',0,25);
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting and where are you seeing it? (e.g. what tool are you using to add the record)

Comment: @payne, `#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1` using `phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of the duplicate value for `id` and not for `title`.

`id` is your primary key so duplicates are not allowed. Also your schema says that `id` is an auto increment field, so you need not enter its value explicitly.

Comment: f. sake this is embarrassing  `id` suppose to be `eid` i thought it was something wrong i did on structure lol :) thnx,

Answer (score 1):

That's because there's already a row with id=1 **OR** because the index on the table is broken, check [this forum thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/11030.htm) about how to fix it with phpmyadmin.